# How to visualize the segmented image of Selective Search?

Tags: python, opencv

How can I visualize the segmented image output of the Selective Search algorithm applied on an image?

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("x.jpg")

ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
ss.setBaseImage(image)

ss.switchToSelectiveSearchQuality()
rects = ss.process()
```

That is, to get the image on the right

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you get any answer? I also want the same for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think the image you require can possibly not be obtained.
Reason being:
[Open this file first containing the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/src/selectivesearchsegmentation.cpp)

In lines 726-734, The variable "images" is private and in the method switchToSelectiveSearchQuality() at line 828, different images used for computation are stored in the private variable "images"(follow addImage function to see).

Also, the images stored in the "images" variable are called for processing segmentation at line 901. Method called here is processImage() of class "GraphSegmentation" which I am not able to trace backwards.

Thus, it is possible that the image you require is not at all stored anywhere or else stored in a private variable which we cannot access.

EDIT: Found "GraphSegmentation" class and method "processImage" declaration in [this file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/include/opencv2/ximgproc/segmentation.hpp) at lines 46 and 52.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following. I tried it - it's working

```
import cv2, random

image = cv2.imread("x.jpg")

ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
ss.setBaseImage(image)

ss.switchToSelectiveSearchQuality()
rects = ss.process()

for i in range(0, len(rects), 100):
    # clone the original image so we can draw on it

    output = image.copy()
    # loop over the current subset of region proposals
    for (x, y, w, h) in rects[i:i + 100]:
        # draw the region proposal bounding box on the image
        color = [random.randint(0, 255) for j in range(0, 3)]
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Output", output)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Why 100? I chose a chunk size of 100.

Original Image:

[image]

After processing:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer and effort. I meant to get the "segmented image", I updated the question to  reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit a confusion.

The image you are trying to create is generated by graph segmentation:

```
  gs = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createGraphSegmentation()

  # Set the sigma, k, and min_size parameters
  gs.setSigma(sigma)
  gs.setK(k)
  gs.setMinSize(min_size)

  # Process the image
  segments = gs.processImage(img)

  # Get the minimum and maximum values in the segments image
  # min, max,_, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(segments)

  # # Get the number of segments
  # nb_segs = int(max + 1)

  # Create an output image
  output = np.zeros_like(img)
  for segment_id in np.unique(segments):
      output[segments == segment_id] = color_mapping(segment_id)

  # Save the output image
  cv2.imwrite(output_image, output)

  print("Image written to " + output_image)
```

graph segmentation works as described here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IVAznQwdS4&ab_channel=FirstPrinciplesofComputerVision

while selective search described here https://learnopencv.com/selective-search-for-object-detection-cpp-python/
is used for bounding box suggestion - i.e. it will produce many suggestion, so that some of the suggestion contains objects

NOTE:

1. Selective search uses graph segmentation as it's first step
2. Selective search is used as suggesting mechanizm for RCNN to avoid scanning the entire img, as explained here https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-regions-with-cnn-features-r-cnn-ec69c15f8ea7
3. The RCNN uses the suggestion to predict objects class, if there is no object in the suggestion, the suggestion is discarded, therefore Selective search require an extra step to discard bad suggestion in order to be usefull